# Attach files to documents in Sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010

Hope this is not a strange question.

Can you attach files to a document item in a document library as you can in a list.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is no.

With SharePoint 2010, you might want to investigate the use of [Document Sets](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/introduction-to-document-sets-HA101782466.aspx) which, without knowing what you're trying to do, could be a way to resolve a need for keeping grouped documents together.

Answer (score 1):

OOTB SharePoint does not support attachments with Document Library.
You should create custom field type or find some commercial add-ons like [Sparqube Document Column](http://sparqube.com/SharePoint-Document-Column/). You can add the Sparqube Document field type to any SharePoint list including Document Library and attach different files within a document item.